# Magento2.3.1 - After install theme :can't use bin/magento CLI

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, theme, magento2.3.1

**Try to install theme name:"UB Trex" for Magento 2.3.1**

so I have followed the instruction to download the zip, and extract it to
localhost,copy `app` and `pub` folder to serve magento root by mobaxterm.

After cover the folder,got a problem :`can't use CLI!`

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is early release bug, you will find it's fix in latest releases

In your function.php file, use this line before function

```
if (!function_exists('__')) {
```

Then `function __()` will look like this:

```
if (!function_exists('__')) {
    /**
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Phrase
     */
    function __()
    {
        $argc = func_get_args();

        $text = array_shift($argc);
        if (!empty($argc) && is_array($argc[0])) {
            $argc = $argc[0];
        }

        return new \Magento\Framework\Phrase($text, $argc);
    }
}
```

This should fix the issue